# Cant remove <p> html tags from string using PHP

Tags: php

I have a weird scenario, I just cant get the

tags removed from a string in PHP.

Here's what happens, I'm pulling out the data from the database with encoding ASCII

The the string looks like this

```
&lt;p&gt;Blue Power Waterproof&lt;/p&gt;
```

Now I do the following to decode the entities

```
html_entity_decode($p->description)
```

with the following results `<p>Blue Power Waterproof</p>` I need to remove the

tags but the following is not working

```
strip_tags(html_entity_decode($p->description))
```

and `removeParagraphTags(html_entity_decode($p->description);`

```
function removeParagraphTags($html){ 
            $pattern = "'#<p[^>]*>(\s|&nbsp;?)*</p>#'"; 
            iconv(mb_detect_encoding($html, "auto"), 'UTF-8', $html);
            return preg_replace($pattern, '', $html); 
        }
```

Comment: `strip_tags(html_entity_decode($str))` works in codepad on `$str = '&lt;p&gt;Blue Power Waterproof&lt;/p&gt;';`. Try `$str = (string) $p->description;` first, before calling functions.

Comment: seems fine to me, are you sure that description is a string?

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with the encoding from the database, if I take the string as above without being pulled form db it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by getting all descriptions from the database that were stored with HTML entities, decoded the entities so that the entities are converted to html, and then updated each record with the html and not with the entity, this fixed the problem

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result=  pg_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result,null,PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $name = html_entity_decode($row['name']);
    $name = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII', $name);
    $desc = html_entity_decode($row['description']);
    $desc = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII', $desc);
    $ldesc = html_entity_decode($row['longDescription']);
    $ldesc = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII', $ldesc);
    $up = "UPDATE products SET name='".pg_escape_string($name)."',description='".  pg_escape_string($desc)."',\"longDescription\"='".pg_escape_string($ldesc)."' WHERE p_id=".$row['p_id'];

    pg_query($conn,$up) OR die(pg_last_error());
}
```